# no internet after switching to a new wifi - ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, internet

after I switched my home server wifi over my new router, the machine doesn't have internet access.

so here is what I did , modified the netplan yaml file in `\etc\netplan\50-clould.yaml`
ran :

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

netlan yaml content :

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    wifis:
        wlo1:
           dhcp4: true
           dhcp6: true
           access-points:
              "SSID":
                   password: "Password"
```

wifi connected successfully and it gets IP , and I'm able to ssh to my machine :

```
$ ip a 

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:f7:72:52:83:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.14/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic wlo1
       valid_lft 258159sec preferred_lft 258159sec
    inet6 fe80::32f7:72ff:fe52:833b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlo1
192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlo1
```

192.168.2.1 is the router ip and I'm not able to ping from within my ubuntu server machine :

```
$ ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.14 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I have to mention if I connect back to my old router , everything works just fine.

here is the network logs :

```
Sep 21 15:51:43 miniserver systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Sep 21 15:51:44 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789904.0433] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Sep 21 15:51:44 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789904.0438] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 10-globally-managed-devices.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: netplan.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Sep 21 15:51:44 miniserver systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Sep 21 15:51:44 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789904.1077] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Sep 21 15:51:44 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789904.1978] manager[0x556a032c5040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Sep 21 15:51:44 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789904.2016] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.3707] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.3708] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "miniserver"
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.3728] dns-mgr[0x556a032aa290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.3778] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver rtl8723be)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.3795] manager[0x556a032c5040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.3796] manager[0x556a032c5040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4272] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4329] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4444] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4549] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4710] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4734] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4744] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4753] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4764] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4892] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4990] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.4990] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789905.4998] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.5081] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.5189] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.5397] device (wlo1): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.5446] manager: (wlo1): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.5894] device (wlo1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789905.6325] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.6887] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.7110] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.7111] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <error> [1663789905.8467] sup-iface[0x556a032d2900,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.8468] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Sep 21 15:51:45 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789905.8470] manager: startup complete
Sep 21 15:51:56 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789916.0140] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1).
Sep 21 15:51:56 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <error> [1663789916.1026] sup-iface[0x556a032d29f0,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Sep 21 15:51:56 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789916.1027] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Sep 21 15:52:06 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789926.0119] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#2).
Sep 21 15:52:06 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <error> [1663789926.1385] sup-iface[0x556a032d2ae0,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Sep 21 15:52:06 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789926.1387] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Sep 21 15:52:16 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789936.0060] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
Sep 21 15:52:16 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <error> [1663789936.1086] sup-iface[0x556a032d2bd0,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Sep 21 15:52:16 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789936.1087] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Sep 21 15:52:26 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789946.0144] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
Sep 21 15:52:26 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <error> [1663789946.1222] sup-iface[0x556a032d2cc0,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Sep 21 15:52:26 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789946.1224] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Sep 21 15:52:36 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1663789956.0066] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
Sep 21 15:52:36 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <error> [1663789956.1053] sup-iface[0x556a032d2cc0,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Sep 21 15:52:36 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789956.1054] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Sep 21 15:52:36 miniserver NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1663789956.1055] device (wlo1): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: That is odd that it is showing the destination of `192.168.2.1` with a netmask of `255.255.255.255` which puts it on its own network.  Public IPs that get assigned to your router will have that subnet, but any system on your network, including your router should not have that subnet mask.  Somehow that is assigned in your route and it should not be.  Everything above that line in your route looks fine.